# Objective C to Swift completion syntax with NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad

I'm trying to rewrite the following to Swift:

```
[client getProductsPage:0 completion:^(NSArray *products, NSUInteger page, BOOL reachedEnd, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        self.products = products;
    } else {
        // Handle errors here
    }
}];
```

One of the several things I tried was:

```
client.getProductsPage(0, completion:{(products:Array, page:UInt, reachedEnd:Bool, error:NSError) -> Void in
        if(error == nil) {
            self.products = products
        } else {
            println("error")
        }
    })
```

I understand that Swift takes away NSError parameters, but if I try removing the error parameter I get a compiler error saying I have a wrong number of parameters. Otherwise, I get "cannot invoke getProductsPage an argument list of type (Int, completion:(Array, UInt, Bool, NSError)->Void)".  I tried several other things but none worked. Any thoughts? Am I doing something else wrong?

(If relevant, the framework for getProductsPage is https://docs.shopify.com/mobile-buy-sdk/ios/api/Classes/BUYClient#//api/name/getProductsPage:completion: )

Comment: Swift 2.0 I presume?

Comment: OK, then all of the discussion about removing error parameters is not applicable (as that's a Swift 2.0 requirement). But it that doesn't apply to block/closure parameters, so that's moot, anyway. The problem is undoubtedly just the optionality/types of the parameters of that block/closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue associated with "Swift takes away `NSError` parameters" is not relevant here. First, that's a Swift 2 feature only. Second, that applies to the `NSError **` parameters of a method, but not to the `NSError *` parameters of a block/closure.

In this case, the issue is probably the nullability of the parameters to that block/closure. For example, the `NSError` parameter certainly should be an optional (because if there is no error, it would be `nil`). If they didn't explicitly audit the class for nullability, I suspect that both the `products` array and the `error` reference would be implicitly unwrapped optionals (e.g. `[AnyObject]!` and `NSError!`, respectively):

```
client.getProductsPage(1, completion: { (products: [AnyObject]!, page: UInt, reachedEnd: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.products = products
    } else {
        // Handle errors here
    }
})
```

If you let Xcode do "code completion" for you, it will show you precisely what those were supposed to be. It's hard to identify what the Swift interface is based solely upon the documentation link you've shared with us. So let Xcode show you what those parameters should be.

By the way, you can often simplify the issue by omitting the types altogether. The Xcode editor/compiler will infer the appropriate types for you:

```
client.getProductsPage(0) { products, page, reachedEnd, error in
    if error == nil {
        self.products = products   // you may have to do a cast here
    } else {
        // Handle errors here
    }
}
```

Note, if you were using Swift 2, you might use `guard`, instead:

```
client.getProductsPage(0) { products, page, reachedEnd, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        // Handle errors here
        return
    }

    self.products = products   // you may have to do a cast here
}
```

Comment: Very appreciated Rob, omitting types did made it work!